# Finding the value of an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given : $a + b + c = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = −2$,

Find $a^4 + b^4 + c^4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever heard of [Newton's Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)?